# React passing state value to parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning react and encounter this problem with the state values. I have a function component(child) that has drop down boxes to select and they all have their own state. When the confirm button is clicked, the state values are passed to the parent class using a prop function.

```
(Child class)
export default function NativeSelects(props){
    const [search_title, setTitle] = useState('')
    const [search_category,setCategory] = useState('')

    return (
        <div>
            <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
                <InputLabel htmlFor="age-native-simple">Title</InputLabel>
                <Select
                    native
                    value={search_title}
                    onChange={e => setTitle(e.target.value)}
                    inputProps={{
                        name: 'search_title',
                        id: 'age-native-simple'
                    }}
                >
                    <option value="" />
                    <option value="option1">option1</option>
                    <option value="option2">option2</option>
                    <option value="option3">option3</option>
                </Select>
            </FormControl> 
            <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
                <InputLabel htmlFor="age-native-helper">Category</InputLabel>
                <Select
                    native 
                    value={search_category}
                    onChange={e => setCategory(e.target.value)}
                    inputProps={{
                        name: 'search_category',
                        id: 'age-native-simple'
                    }}
                >
                    <option value=""/>
                    <option value="option1">option1</option>
                    <option value="option2">option2</option>
                    <option value="option3">option3</option>
                </Select>
            </FormControl>
            <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={props.handler(search_title,search_category)}>Search</Button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

```
(Parent class)
searchProduct = (title,category) =>{
    fetch(`/search?title='${title}'&category='${category}'`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => this.setState({ products: response.data }))
    .catch(err => console.error(err))
  }

  render(){
    return (
        <ChildClass handler = {() => this.searchProduct}/>
    )
  }
```

When I check the state values inside the child class, it is changing properly. But in the parent class the first value becomes an object and the second value becomes undefined. 
What did I do wrong here?

Comment: your handler prop looks weird to me, try
`<ChildClass handler = {(title, category) => this.searchProduct(title, category)}/>`

Comment: if you want to change values in parent you have to handle state in parent and pass down callback functions to change it or you use redux to handle global state

Answer (score 0):

Change parent class handler function call

```
return (
        <ChildClass handler = {(title,category)=>this.searchProduct(title,category)}/>
    )
```

Changes in Child class:

```
 <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={(title,category)=>props.handler(search_title,search_category)}>Search</Button>
```

Comment: it works as it gets the parameters but it keep triggering the handler function.

Comment: @JohnnyLiang Updated my answer. Check now.

Answer (score 0):

change to following in Parent class.

```
<ChildClass handler = {this.searchProduct}/>
```

change in Child class

```
<Button
  variant="contained"
  color="primary"
  onClick={() => props.handler(search_title, search_category)}
>
  Search
</Button>;
```

Comment: it works as it gets the parameters but it keep triggering the handler function.

Comment: @JohnnyLiang, Updated the answer. Also need to change in child class. call handler only on click.